# Why does react-select not output anything while there is an object array available?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

The react-select seems working without any issue.  If the object structure is for instance like:

```js
{ value: 'ocean', label: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9', isFixed: true },
{ value: 'blue', label: 'Blue', color: '#0052CC', isDisabled: true },
```

But why does it not work with the following object structure (unfortunately I am not allowed to change the key name and/or structure):

```js
{ "id": 5, "name": "Pop" },
{ "id": 6, "name": "Electronic/Dance" },
{ "id": 8, "name": "Rock" },
```

[Click on the link to codesandbox to understand the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-cwbyz?file=/example.js)

So the question is how can I make this work in my case.

Comment: `value` is required. When you select any option, is the value of `value` what is outputed

Comment: And in your Code sandbox/ docs/data there isn't exported `GenreList`. Anyways, for `react-select` options, the `label` key is what you want to show on the option, and `value` the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the following object structure (unfortunately I am not allowed to change the key name and/or structure)

You can always use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the array to another array that has the option structure that `react-select` recognizes (by default [`{ label: string; value: string }`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/09d10b62b777a53de18067a2bb6b8bf68a73a758/types/react-select/src/Select.d.ts#L56)):

```
const selectOptions = yourOptions.map(o => ({ value: o.id, label: o.name }))
```